# AWS Batch: how to increase concurrency for Fargate jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I'm trying to use Batch for large-scale parallelised job execution, with Docker containers. I would like to process thousands of tasks simultaneously.

I have everything up and running. My compute environment is configured with a max vCPUs of 2048. Each task is configured to use a single vCPU, and 2GB of RAM. I am using an array job with 1,000 array elements (for now).

Problem is: when I create a new job, concurrency seems to be extremely limited. When I look at the cluster in ECS, "pending tasks" seems to constantly hover around 50 (it might not ever go above 50), and "running tasks" doesn't go far above 30. Even though each individual task only takes ~10 seconds to complete, the entire batch takes ~20 minutes.

This isn't what I expected. With the above settings, I thought Batch would process all 1,000 tasks at the same time.

I originally thought the problem might have been caused by my use of a public subnet (all Fargate containers had public IPs). I changed to use a private subnet (with NAT gateway), but it didn't help.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you rule out that a service quota is not restricting your maximum concurrent Fargate tasks? 

https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/

Comment: Ruled out.  Fargate spot resource count has a limit of 500, but I'm not getting anywhere close.

Comment: AWS Batch does not scale compute environments immediately. The job scheduling and resource allocation services look across all your queues and resources to determine what and when to start resources, and what to place on them. Spot allocation also adds overhead. Do you see the same behavior for on-demand resources?

Comment: Another note about scaling: Fargate was designed to quickly scale for running microservices, which is a different sort of scaling than a batch workload. Two options -> use an EC2 CE, which will provision a larger instance that will allow placement of many tasks on the same host while still taking advantage of Spot Instances; or move to something like AWS Lambda since your runtime and resources fit within it's constraints, but no Spot market.

Comment: Disclosure - I am a Developer Advocate for AWS Batch. The issue is Fargate rate-limiting scaling the number of tasks run. Using an EC2 CE doesn't change your containers, but you will need a new Job Queue & CE, and your Job Definition will need to define the [`platformCapabilities`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#job-definition-parameters-platform-capabilities)  as `EC2`.  Batch will launch a large instance to run  tasks in parallel, so you may see a slower time-to-start but much quicker time-to-scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is in the comments above, but for posterity:

The AWS Batch Compute Environment with Fargate resources is not scaling fast enough for your needs, since each job launches in it's own Fargate resource. Using EC2 for the Compute Environment will launch a large instance that will run multiple jobs on it concurrently, so scaling running jobs will be much faster.

As to why you are seeing that max (pending 50 running 30) this is likely because your requests reached an equilibrium of launching / finished. If your jobs ran longer than 10 seconds (minutes) you would see the total number of running tasks would go higher than you are seeing.

Comment: Hi Angel.  I just circled back to this, and tried EC2.  No material change in the overall time to job completion :(

I tried a number of allocation strategies, including SPOT_CAPACITY_OPTIMIZED.  It caused a lot (> 50) EC2 instances to be created when I submit my Batch array job.  Which is great.  But jobs still seem to be started ~50 at a time.  And the next 50 don't get started until some time after that.  The result is that my EC2 resources are mostly idle, and my array job takes a long time.  Any thoughts on why this is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah something else is happening. Expected behavior is filling those instances up. Can you email me directly at pizarroa at amazon so we can have quicker back and forth? We can post final answer to SO once we have it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here -- using ec2 as the compute environment does not fix it.

Comment: @StuartClarke Was there a resolution for this? I am also in the same boat. Hovering at about 30% of my fargate spot quota. It would be great if I could pro-actively issue a scaling command as the workload was starting.